# Read a multi nested Dictionary value into column in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I have some hardware that outputs data as nested dictionaries.

```
data_out = {'unimportant_dict': [{'dateTime': '2019-12-01', 'value': '183'}], 'secondary_dict': {'sub_dict': [{'time': '00:00:00', 'value': 0}, {'time': '00:01:00', 'value': 0}, {'time': '00:02:00', 'value': 0}], 'datasetInterval': 1}}
```

I am interested in the 'value' data in 'sub_dict' which I want to read into a Pandas df, but I have multiple files to collate into a single dataframe.

I can read one file in which works fine

```
tempdict = data_out['secondary_dict']
testdf = pd.DataFrame(tempdict['sub_dict'])
```

Which gives

```
       time        value
     0  00:00:00      0
     1  00:01:00      0
     2  00:02:00      0
     3  00:03:00      0
     4  00:04:00      0
```

Now I want to add a second file but ONLY the value data (because the timestamps will always be same).  Assuming a second file with the same structure as above my approach is wrong.

```
tempdict2 = data_out2['secondary_dict']['value']   
testdf['new data'] = tempdict2
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I think this is because it is a long list of dicts (I assume its a list to preserve the time order). I thought I could just add it and then delete the additional time column but it adds the whole dict as a single column

```
          time  value                              fle2
   0  00:00:00      0  {'time': '00:00:00', 'value': 0}
   1  00:01:00      0  {'time': '00:01:00', 'value': 0}
   2  00:02:00      0  {'time': '00:02:00', 'value': 0}
   3  00:03:00      0  {'time': '00:03:00', 'value': 0}
   4  00:04:00      0  {'time': '00:04:00', 'value': 0}
```

As Im writing, I'm wondering if it would be easier to extract the 'value' values to a list and then add that to the df?

I don't think this is a duplicate of
[Capture python value from multi-nested dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51389749/capture-python-value-from-multi-nested-dictionary)
since that is still a single dict as a list, whereas this is lots of dicts in a list.

any help appreciated.

Comment: do u mind having a look at the data u shared, there is an error somewhere. also, could u share a small sample of the second file, so whoever works on ur request can get the full picture. post a final output df as well.

Comment: Sorry - I wasn't clear in the file data.  That data has about 1400 entries so I truncated (which I tried to indicate with ... but given this is a coding site that was a bad idea.  Have updated.

Answer (score 1):

First, read all your data into a list named `all_nested_dicts`. I am assuming you have same number of records in all your files and the `time` values  are same for all the files. Without this two assumptions in place, the solution below is not going to work as I simply merge the dataframes by concatenating them.

```py
dfs = []
for i, nested_dict in enumerate(all_nested_dicts):
    df = pd.DataFrame(nested_dict['secondary_dict']['sub_dict']).rename(columns = {'value': f'value_{i}'})
    df.sort_values("time", inplace = True)
    # drop the `time` column from all subsequent files after sorting
    if i >= 1:
        df.drop("time", axis = 1, inplace = True)
    dfs.append(df)

final_df = pd.concat(dfs, axis = 1)
```

Comment: Thanks - this worked.  I've actually a lot of files rather than 2 in the example, so have defined a simple function based on this.